# Shnayim Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

192 is the gematria of the phrase בכל מכל כל, representing of the blessings that Avraham, Yitzchak, and Yaakov enjoyed - "with all" (Gen. 24:1), "from all" (ibid. 27:33), and "all" (ibid. 33:11).

It is also the combined gematria of four names of Hashem that make up the complete configuration of sefiros in Atzilus: י"ה = 15, אלקים = 86, הוי"ה = 26, אדנ"י = 65.

[(Chasam Sofer to Bava Basra 17a)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21734&pgnum=53)

Answer (score 5):

[Rashi Kedushin 12a - Alpha V'Chamaish Maioh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14313&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=) says that there are 192 Perutos in a Dinar.

Answer (score 1):

There [reportedly](http://books.google.com/books?&id=A5lCAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22one+hundred+and+ninety-two%22&q=%22one+hundred+and+ninety-two%22) were 192,000 Jews in Austria at the time of the [Anschluss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss). But other sources give other numbers.